# How to Force postfix send from specific ip

Tags: email, postfix, ubuntu-16.04

My mail server has 2 public IPs:

```
IP1: 1.1.1.1 (eth0)
IP2: 2.2.2.2 (eth0:1)
```

Currently my mx, a, ptr, spf records are pointing to the "2.2.2.2" ip, which i need to be for the mail server only,

But currently when i send any mail, the postfix `3.1.0` decides to send it on "1.1.1.1" ip,

I tried to make the `master.cf`:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd

  -o smtp_bind_address=2.2.2.2

smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd

  -o smtp_bind_address=2.2.2.2

relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
  -o smtp_bind_address=2.2.2.2
```

But it still sends from the "1.1.1.1"

Any help please?

Comment: Are these public IP addresses directly connected to the server? Or is there an intermediary router with NAT and/or port forwarding?

Comment: Yes both are public IPs

Comment: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_interfaces . There are indications there

Comment: I’m not sure if postfix has a specific option to handle this. But you should be able to do this with policy routing rules. You can route all traffic destined to/from port 25 over that particular gateway.